# how can i get list of member which dont have a matching team name?

Tags: php, mysql

Basically, I want to get data from the database. The data I want is a people/member without a match team name. In the registration form every member have to fill a team name and then select a category, let's say category A must have a 2 member for each team. Now I want a list of member which don't have a match team name. How is the logic?

What I'm thinking is:

1. get a list of team name
2. do a looping to check if there is there a member with the same team name and category ( num rows less than or exactly 1 )
3. list the result

I haven't written any code, because I'm confused with the logic on how I would do it. Hope you guys can provide me with some feedback.

Also, I'm currently using `Codeigniter`.

**EDIT #1**

Here is the table structure

```
ID | NAME | CATEGORY | TEAM
1  | Person 1 | CAT A | TEAM A
2  | PERSON 2 | CAT A | TEAM A
3  | PERSON 3 | CAT A | TEAM B
```

What I want in the result is someone without other team member, so the result would be:

```
3  | PERSON 3 | CAT A | TEAM B
```

because the other have a matching team

Comment: All you need is a join (an outer join, in this instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this may help you:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  NAME,
  category,
  teams.team 
FROM
  teams 
  INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      team 
    FROM
      teams 
    GROUP BY team 
    HAVING COUNT(id) = 1) diff 
    ON teams.team = diff.team ;
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c696f/5/0)

Comment: hey @felipe , this is almost perfect, but i only want to do it with one of member tipe , so i try adding tipe = 'tipe a' but it doesnt work, where should i put the where clause ? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfb44f/3 . thanks anyway :)

Comment: oh sorry i forgot that where clause should be at the end. its solved . thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE category = 'CAT A'
   AND team != 'TEAM A'
```

Comment: hey @alex thanks for the answer, but this doesn't solve the problem. because in registration form they fill their team name. so there would be a lot of team name in the table. and some of them dont have a matching team name . that is what i want to be the result.